# Magnet on gps module - will it harm?

Tags: gps, modules

Maybe a stupid question, but really importnt to me.

So I'm making some app with a pi, lcd and a **GPS module**. The gps module is a board with an extention cable of 5m, with a module at the end of it. This is the module I'm talking about;

[Module](https://www.amazon.de/GPS-Expansion-Board-f%C3%BCr-Raspberry/dp/0284906646/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1487508048&sr=8-10&keywords=raspberry%20pi%20gps%20expansion%20board)

Will the gps still work if I put magnets underneath it to stick it outside of the car (on the roof) and is it weather proof or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no, a magnet will not interfere with your GPS module.**

The reason is that the electric field strength of the GPS signal will not be altered in any significant way by the relatively modest magnetic field of your magnet.  Also, if the intent of the magnet is to temporarily affix the module the metal of your vehicle, most of the magnetic field will be within the metal  which has a much higher relative magnetic permeability than air.

Comment: I bought a magnetic antenna, so it doesn't harm the module. Thanks!